# Finding biggest and smallest numbers using user input

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Well it is a problem about finding the biggest and smallest number in a group of numbers, but we do not know how many numbers the user wants-

So far this is what i have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{

int num;
int i;
int maxi=0;
int minim=0;
int cont = 0;

printf ("\nQuantity of numbers?: ");
scanf ("%d", &num);
while (num>0)
    {
    printf ("\nEnter number:");
    scanf ("%d", &i);
    if (num>i)
        minim=i++;

    else
        if (i>num)
            max=i++;
            cont++;
}

printf ("\nBiggest number is es: %d", maxi);
printf ("\nSmallest number is: %d", minim);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I did my program to ask how many numbers the user will want to put and i made the program to read them, BUT when it reads the biggest or/and smallest numbers it will sometimes changes biggest with small and it will not read negative numbers.

How do i do to make my program better?

Comment: It is kinda working, but it doesn't gives me the biggest and smallest number most of times, it messes them up. SO i have troubles in finding my output, but i do not know where exactly.

Comment: Why compare with `num` -- the number of inputs? You should compare the input against `mini` and `maxi` (and you may want to set `mini` to a large value).

Comment: what value would you recommend for `mini` ?

Comment: Suggest `int maxi=INT_MIN; int minim=INT_MAX;`

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing against the wrong values.

```
do 
{
   printf("Enter a number.\n");
   scanf("%i", &input);
   if min > input 
     min = input
   if max < input
     max = input   
}   while (input > 0);
```

Comment: Can`t use `do` but did something and it works. Only problem is when it reads negatives numbers, it prints the smallest negative right, but it prints 2 as the biggest number even if i only entered negatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    int num;
    int i;
    int maxi=0;
    int minim=INT_MAX;
    int cont = 0;

    printf ("\nQuantity of numbers?: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num > 0){
        while (num>0){
            printf ("\nEnter number:");
            if(scanf("%d", &i) == 1 && !(i<0)){
                if(minim > i)
                    minim = i;
                if (maxi < i)
                    maxi = i;
                ++cont;
                --num;
            } else {
                //fprintf(stderr, "redo input!\n")
                ;
            }
            scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
        }

        printf ("\nBiggest number is : %d", maxi);
        printf ("\nSmallest number is : %d\n", minim);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `mini` to the largest possible int, i.e. `INT_MAX` and `maxi` to the smallest possible int, i.e., `INT_MIN`. This way, even if the first number is negative, it will be considered for `maxi`, and if the first number is positive it will still be considered for `mini`. The constants `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` are included in `<climits>` or `<limits.h>`.

Also, you are comparing the current entered number with `num`, which is the counter  of numbers entered by user, not one of the values he wants to compare. A better modified code would be :

```
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int num;
    int maxi=INT_MIN;     //initialize max value
    int mini=INT_MAX;     //initialize min value
    int temp;
    scanf("%d", &num);    //take in number of numbers

    while(num--)          //loop "num" times, num decrements once each iteration of loop
    {

        scanf("%d", &temp);    //Take in new number
        if(temp>maxi)          //see if it is new maximum
            maxi=temp;     //set to new maximum
        if(temp<mini)          //see if new minimum
            mini=temp;     //set to new minimum
    }
    printf("\nMaxi is:\t%d\nMini is:\t%d\n", maxi, mini);   //print answer
    return 0;
}
```