# I want a c program to find maximum and minimum number i have written using arrays can someone help me how can i make without using arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, max, computer-science, min

Write a C program to display the Maximum and Minimum numbers from 10 numbers given by the
user inputs. (without using arrays). I want help me with this code how can I write without using arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int arr1[100];
    int i, mx, mn, n;
    
    
       printf("\n\nFind maximum and minimum element in an array :\n");
       printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");  

       printf("Input the number of elements to be stored in the array :");
       scanf("%d",&n);
   
       printf("Input %d elements in the array :\n",n);
       for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
          printf("element - %d : ",i);
          scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
        }

mx = arr1[0];
    mn = arr1[0];

    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]>mx)
        {
            mx = arr1[i];
        }


        if(arr1[i]<mn)
        {
            mn = arr1[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Maximum element is : %d\n", mx);
    printf("Minimum element is : %d\n\n", mn);
}
```

Comment: You only need three variables - `max`, `min`, `current`. Read the first number into `current` and copy same value into `max` and `min`. Then read each subsequent number into `current` and compare with `max` and `min` to update those as needed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195200/finding-biggest-and-smallest-numbers-using-user-input

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, num, i, max, min;
    printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter the numbers\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    max = num; //Assuming that the first number is the maximum
    min = num; //Assuming that the first number is the minimum
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if (num > max)
            max = num;
        if (num < min)
            min = num;
    }
    printf("The maximum number is %d", max);
    printf("The minimum number is %d", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you... also don't forget to upvote. And if you have any doubt, feel free to comment